# How can I make a fairly efficient chicken farm?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I made a chicken farm in FTB, but it created hundreds of chickens in one night, and that's not okay. I need a way to slaughter them every now and then. You can add mods to the pack. Killing the babies is okay, but I need to make it in a way that it's renewable and will never run out of chickens. What is the best design for this?

Comment: Use pistons to divide to wall off a small section then flood it. All the chickens in that bit drown but the rest live.

Comment: In FTB, why not just use a grinder?

Comment: @immibis What mod is that?

Comment: [I made this.](http://www.planetminecraft.com/project/fully-automatic-renewable-chicken-farm/)

Comment: @WhynoTalos That's seems rather complex. Since there are mods, we can have a tree farm, reducing the need for the Wither skeletons. Rather nice setup using only vanilla materials though. I guess I'm looking for something a bit more compact though.

Comment: It was a PITA to set up.

Comment: Phrases I thought I'd never read: "*Killing the babies is okay...*"

Comment: I would imagine this could be as simple as placing a magma pit in the chicken pen.  As the number of chickens becomes "too dense", they'll push each other into the magma pit, which keeps an upper limit on the chicken density.  I expect they won't jump in on purpose, so there's no fear that the last one will randomly jump in.

Comment: @JeffreyLin MineFactory Reloaded.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The best design for this uses the principles that Xisumivoid used in his [Automatic Cooked Chicken Farm Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tWT_WCTFUvA) - check out that video if you want to see exactly how it's built.

The core of it all is the dispenser launching eggs into a half-slab, with lava above it. Baby chickens sit on top of the half slab, and grow up into the lava, where thy are cooked to perfection automatically without even worrying about putting it in a furnace. Like so:

[image: The front side of the chicken farm]

There's a hopper right underneath the slab that puts the drops in the chest (it's slightly hidden, but it's there, trust me).

The chickens above are feeding eggs into the dispenser. There really isn't a best design for this. If you want to make this whole thing as compact as possible, check out Xisuma's video. Otherwise, some chickens on top of a hopper that eventually leads to your dispenser in some fashion will do fine.

The auto-shooter redstone is implemented as follows:

[image: Egg auto-shooter design]

Of course, with this being a modded pack, you can make this run however you want. This design only runs when there is an egg inside the dropper, reducing the potential lag. You can also, of course, use transfer pipes if you really want to. Like I said, the important part here is that the chickens are shot onto a slab, grow up, and get cooked and eaten. The circle of life.

Answer (score 5):

This is a subjective question. There is no "best" design because everybody will have different opinions.

In my opinion, this is quite a nice and simple one, using only mine-craft vanilla! He also gives a great explanation on the building aspect of it.

Here's the run-down of it:

1. you have dispensers that you can load with eggs and set to hatch eggs.
2. you can flood the chicken box to send the kitchens in one of two pits.
3. you can than crush the chickens and gather all the loot.

That's the most efficient method. Here's a fully automatic method:

It works very well and it's vanilla too!

Comment: It's semi-automatic. You have to put eggs into dispensers to hatch, wait for it to hatch, and once you see the chickens in the box, you can flush it and crush it.

Comment: Jeez, you never mentioned you wanted it automatic :O

Comment: Added an automatic version

Answer (score 0):

MFR planter + harvester = seeds seeds + breeder = babies babies + chronotyper = sorting another chronotyper for removing adults into lava cooker or straight up slaugherhouse or grinder